Estimate of a trigonometric product
Let $P_n(x) = \sin(x)\sin(2x)\cdots\sin(2^n x)$
Is it true that $ \max |P_n| \leq C \times 2^{-n/2}$?

I presume $2^{-n/2}$ comes from the $L^2$-norm, right? Have you tried computing $L^4$-norm, say?

On MSE is proven that $\vert\sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(2^2x)\cdots\sin(2^nx)\vert < \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$ from a Putnam problem

No. Sharp exponent is $\sqrt{3}/2>1/\sqrt{2}$ (cf. Dabed's comment), attained for $x=\pi/3$.

Let me try to give a reason why I believe the answer is no, and how it might be possible to obtain an exponentially better lower bound.
As I said in the comment, by looking at the $L^2$-norm on $(0, 2\pi)$ with respect to the measure $\frac{dx}{2\pi}$, and then looking at the Fourier series side there would be no cancellations so $||P_n||_{L^2} = 2^{-n/2}$, from where we get the lower bound $\max |P_n| \ge 2^{-n/2}$. So, I computed the $L^4$-norm of $P_n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. Specifically, let's multiply $P_n$ by $2^n$, then $Q_n^2 = (2^n P_n)^2 = (4\sin^2(x))(4\sin^2(2x))\ldots (4\sin^2(2^nx))$, and $4\sin^2(x)$ has only integer Fourier coefficients. Then we get a sequence of $||Q_n||_{L^4}^4$ starting as $6, 28, 152, 752, 3936$.
Now, I will go to the realm of pure speculation. I tried plugging this sequence into OEIS, but got no answers. However, I noticed that the first term is divisible by $2$, the next one by $4$, the third one by $8$. So, I decided to look at this sequence, divided by $2^k$, and got a sequence $3, 7, 19, 47, 123$. This sequence is in OEIS, and there is only one such sequence! It is the sequence A026581. And this sequence satisfies a linear recurrence $a_{k} = a_{k-1} + 4a_{k-2}$. Its growth can be computed by standard methods, it grows like $\alpha^k$, where $\alpha = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{17}}{2} = 2.56\ldots > 2$. If we believe that this pattern of the $L^4$-norm continues, this will give us a lower bound for $||P_n||_{L^4}$ which is $C \left(\frac{\alpha}{8}\right)^{1/4}$, which is exponentially bigger than $2^{-n/2}$.
So, it remains to prove that the pattern continues, but I don't see at the moment how to prove it, maybe some sort of induction or something?

Thank you for the answers. Unfortunately the inequality

Thank you for the answers. Unfortunately the inequality $|sin(x)...sin(2^n x)| \leq (\sqrt(3)/2)^n is false already for n=2. The maximum of $|sin(x)sin(2x)$ is $4\sqrt(3)/9 > 3/4$. I have no idea what the sharp estimate might be. Arkady Kitover

I don't think you meant to reply to my post. Anyway, if you look at the proof referenced by Dabed you will see that it actually proves $|\sin(x)\ldots \sin(2^nx)| \le \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{n-1}$, with $n-1$ and not with $n$. But it is still more than enough to disprove your conjecture.

Thank you, that answers my question.

Many thanks to Fedor and Alexei. Their help allowed me to prove that the spectrum of the operator $(Tf)(z) = (1-z)/2 \times f(z^2)$ on the disc algebra is the disk of radius $\sqrt(3)/2$

I wonder if anything is known about the asymptotic behavior of more general products

$sin(x-a)...sin(2^n x -a)$, where $a$ is areal number?

This comment section is definitely not the place to ask such questions.
